# Помогите новичку с кодом для построения графика функции на VS (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Доброго времени суток, изучаю на втором курсе С++, дали задание написать код программы для построения графика уравнения 2cosx-4,5x+0.76=0 интервалы(xn=0 xk=1) шаг dx=0.05
Пытался в интернете найти аналог кода,менял значения на свои но он у меня не рабоатет.

Comment: может код покажешь?
а вообще посмотри примеры про WM_PAINT
если же и этого недостаточно, то значит стоит начать учить азы C++
без этого любая помощь - лишь поможет сдать зачет, но не прибавить ни знания, ни опыта

Comment: @Zhihar я бы с радостью сидел и разбирался как строить эти графики, если бы срок на проект не был бы 5 дней.

Comment: так в чем именно проблема? где случился затык? есть исходик, с которым ты работал? Что именно не получилось?  Просто у тебя в текущем виде вопрос звучит так "напишите мне с 0 программу построения графика". Задача разбивается на 2 - цикл вычисления y(x) в нужном диапазоне и интерфейс приложения - в какой из этих задач затык?

Comment: @Zhihar исходник был взят из методички, весь код с точностью 100% переписал, но выбивало ошибку(в коде есть условие
               cout << "Error" << grapherrormsg(errorcode);
  cout << "\n Press any key";
  getch();
  exit(1);
которое всегда срабатывало и выводило Ошибку, всё бы было хорошо, но если бы мне объяснили как написать код, чего не было сделано на лекции

Comment: вот по той информации, что ты дал, можно с уверенностью сказать, что код написал на c++ :) Теперь от тебя осталось узнать требования к программе - что должно использоваться, например оконный или консольный (досовский) вариант графики, если оконный, то что именно можно использовать: WinAPI, MFC, WTL, Qt или DirectX. Опять же можно попробовать выложить исходник (у меня например по телепатии была в институте тройка). Думаю за 4 дня мы ТЗ с тобой сможем выяснить. Пока (с учетом 2 твоих ответов) пока все неясно - пока еще это "напишите программу".
Хотя виноват: есть grapherrormsg - тз ясна

Comment: @Zhihar судя по фоткам из методички, то вариант графики консольный.  исходник из методички:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WMBkro4E4aLm8CHzOVQOf7v2lrExwYHU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Я так и подумал (функция grapherrormsg), странно, что в исходнике еще и <windows.h> используется, поскольку никаких вызовов нет. Теперь о grapherrormsg - "Функция уникальна  для  Borland C++.  Она работает только на компьютерах IBM PC и совместимых с ними,
 оснащенных дисплейными адаптерами, поддерживающими
графический   режим.   Функция   не  совместима  с Windows.". А вы про Visual Studio говорите. "В 1997 году выходит последний релиз Borland C++ IDE" - У вас практические занятия были? Как компьютеры выглядели? Какую ошибку выдает у вас программа? Что графика не инициализируется?

Comment: Мы свои носили с VS 2017(а какие там ПК были, если я скажу 512mb RAM, то думаю дальше пояснять не стоит), было бы меньше мороки с этим кодом, если бы нам хоть дали пример или скелет кода, но нам просто дали пример кода из той методички и всё, а как адаптировать это всё под современный формат видимо забыли рассказать.

Comment: под современный формат - я бы лично все переписал бы с 0 хотя бы с WinAPI (оконный интерфейс) типа https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms533895(v=vs.85).aspx. Или так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUdJuRlcUvU. И вот тут http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=328647&seqNum=3. А вот это тебе наверное подойдет еще лучше: http://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/getting-started-with-windows-gdi-graphics-applications-in-c/

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, то цикл программы прерываеться на if и дальше просто не идет, потому что в if  есть cout с Error и при компиляции я вижу Error. Проблема в том, что мне нужно не просто линии нарисовать, а график уравнения с интервалом и с шагом

Comment: ну а компилятор на что ругается? или программа запускается - тогда что она выводит на экран? это же консольное приложение. Но вообще оно не для VS. Касательно того, что нужен график, а не линии - чтобы бегать, надо сначала научиться ходить. За 5 дней несложно будет освоить и рисование и построить график (если есть азы работы с C++ и понимание этого языка)

Comment: Компилятор не ругаеться, он просто выводит то, что прописываешь в cout (Error)да и + потом ко всему этото .exe этого проекта крашиться с какими-то проблемами, ну почему он крашит то я думаю понять не сложно(из-за адаптации)

Comment: http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/basic/graphics/graphics.html вот тут пример рисования графиков (можно скачать исходники)

Comment: Ну а вообще график это только часть проекта, а весь он состоит из разветвления. На начале у нас стоит выбор или график, или просто табулирование этой же ф-ции. Вот со вторым проблем я думаю не возникнет, а вот с графиком......